# Spark sql operation takes long time

Tags: apache-spark

million I have nested json structure with struct with elements, I read the json -> deduplicate -> flatten. The data after read the count is around .8 million and after dedup the count is around .2 million and I flatten this .2 million data and apply simple count it is running forever, Believe am working with huge data and taking time. See that some stages finishes faster but, some stages are just stuck for ex:

```
[Stage 3:>                                                      (0 + 124) / 200]
```

How to over come this ? Using below spark settings

```
--driver-memory 20G 
--executor-memory 29G 
--executor-cores 4 
--num-executors 100
```

Comment: Can you please share you code along with input & expected output, without that it is difficult to provide solution.